# The case of the Missing-Index-Not!

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I ran the code found here:
[SQLServerPedia Find Missing Indexes](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Find_Missing_Indexes#SQLServerPedia_Fan_Contribution) (sic) and it reported an index missing (one column in the equality column, none in the inequality column, and none in the included column).

However, this index already exists! I've updated stats on the index, on the table, dropped and recreated the index in question, run sp_recompile on the table. It still shows up in the list as MIA (and at the top of the list to boot)...

Any ideas on what to do from here? TIA for the help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database Tuning Advisor recommends to create an existing index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113786/database-tuning-advisor-recommends-to-create-an-existing-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "DESC" to the index. And then restart the SQL instance to reset the informations

It worked before: [Database Tuning Advisor recommends to create an existing index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113786/database-tuning-advisor-recommends-to-create-an-existing-index/1113821#1113821)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! (Although I didn't have to restart SQL Server)