# After adding index Execution Plan SqlServer keeps suggesting the index

Tags: sql-server

If I run the execution plan of an sp, Management Studio suggests an index. I add the index, run the execution plan again, and it keeps suggesting the same index... What am I doing wrong here? I already restarted SqlServer and Management Studio, but that's doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index column order and sort order?

See this please: [Database Tuning Advisor recommends to create an existing index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113786/database-tuning-advisor-recommends-to-create-an-existing-index/1113821#1113821)