# Why does Sql Server recommend creating an index when it already exist?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, query-analyzer

I ran a very basic query against one of our table and I noticed that the execution plan query processor is recommending that we create an index on a column

The query is

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Data))
FROM Item
WHERE Namespace = 'http://some_url/some_namespace/'
```

After running, I get the following message

```
// The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 96.7211%.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Item] ([Namespace])
```

My problem is that I already have such index on that column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemNamespace] ON [dbo].[Item] 
(
    [Namespace] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Why is Sql Server recommending me to create such index when it already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index column and sort order make a difference...

Previous [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442592/after-adding-index-execution-plan-sqlserver-keeps-suggesting-the-index/2442618#2442618) and [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113786/database-tuning-advisor-recommends-to-create-an-existing-index/1113821#1113821)

However, for something this simple try adding an [INCLUDE clause](http://drsql.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!80677FB08B3162E4!402.entry) to make it covering.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemNamespace] ON [dbo].[Item] ([Namespace]) INCLUDE ([Data])
```

Comment: Nice, I won't do that on the data column, but that gives me some idea some other places where it could be useful.